# Android Kotlin Twitter Login Errors

Tags: android, firebase, kotlin, authentication, idp

I can get to the https://api.twitter.com/oauth/authenticate?oauth_token=... web page.
Then the activity ends the connection and stops the web browser and leaves my app going nowhere.

The log statements are below:

```
2024-01-10 14:42:09.688  2735-2735  GenericIdpActivity      com...wavejumper.personallocker.pro  I  Opening IDP Sign In link in a browser window.
2024-01-10 14:42:09.720  2735-27836 FA                      com...wavejumper.personallocker.pro  V  Recording user engagement, ms: 2396
2024-01-10 14:42:09.975  2735-27836 FA                      com...wavejumper.personallocker.pro  V  Activity paused, time: 10992381
2024-01-10 14:42:11.957  2735-2735  WindowOnBackDispatcher  com...wavejumper.personallocker.pro  W  sendCancelIfRunning: isInProgress=falsecallback=android.view.ViewRootImpl$$ExternalSyntheticLambda17@d0d44d2
```

I have tried three different approaches from the web. all get to here and stop.
My secrets, callback and tokens seem to be good.
I can't find a Kotlin that works.